# Spring Boot KeyCloak Override ClientIdAndSecretCredentialsProvider not working

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I am trying to override `ClientIdAndSecretCredentialsProvider` in KeyCloak Spring Boot. Below is the code I have tried.

```
public class CustomClientCredentialsProvider extends ClientIdAndSecretCredentialsProvider {

    public static final String PROVIDER_ID = CredentialRepresentation.SECRET;

    private String clientSecret;

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return PROVIDER_ID;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(KeycloakDeployment deployment, Object config) {
        clientSecret = (String) config;
    }

    @Override
    public void setClientCredentials(KeycloakDeployment deployment, Map<String, String> requestHeaders, Map<String, String> formParams) {
        String clientId = deployment.getResourceName();

        if (!deployment.isPublicClient()) {
            if (clientSecret != null) {
                // do something else
            }
        } else {
            formParams.put(OAuth2Constants.CLIENT_ID, clientId);
        }
    }
}
```

However even after overwrite, I can still see the control going to the existing Spring Boot's `ClientIdAndSecretCredentialsProvider` rather than mine.

How can I get the control to mine rather than Spring Boot's? Is there something else that needs to be set??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to pass an instance of CustomClientCredentialsProvider to the Adapter Deployment.
See [`AdapterDeploymentContext#setClientAuthenticator(ClientCredentialsProvider clientAuthenticator)`](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/bfce612641a70e106b20b136431f0e4046b5c37f/adapters/oidc/adapter-core/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/AdapterDeploymentContext.java#L252)