# Spring Boot Keycloak Client Credentials in request body

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I have an application that uses Keycloak Spring Boot Starter and communicates with a custom variant of Keycloak for the token generation. The problem is that the application sends the client credentials in the request header (`ClienIdAndClientCredentialsProvider`) as the standard way. I want to the client credentials to be sent in the request body rather since the custom variant of Keycloak expects it in the request body.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: Reference to whatever I tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69802099/spring-boot-keycloak-override-clientidandsecretcredentialsprovider-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file under `src/main/resources/META-INF/services` with name `org.keycloak.adapters.authentication.ClientCredentialsProvider` with contents:

```
com.whatever.app.CustomClientCredentialsProvider
```

In the `application.properties` file change it like this:

```
// Provider names should be same as PROVIDER_ID and not be existing like secret, jwt, etc
keycloak.credentials.custom=xxxxx
keycloak.credentials.provider=custom
```

And in your `CustomClientCredentialsProvider` change the following line:

```
public static final String PROVIDER_ID = "custom";
```